# using npm in vscode cause "Error: Cannot find module 'semver' "

Tags: linux, path, visual-studio-code

If I start the project on vscode terminal:

`npm run start`

i get this errror:

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1083
throw err;
^

```
Error: Cannot find module 'semver'
Require stack:
- /usr/share/nodejs/npm/lib/utils/unsupported.js
- /usr/share/nodejs/npm/lib/cli.js
- /usr/share/nodejs/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
```

I check `npm --version`, it gives me error.

I run this command: `export PATH="/usr/bin:$PATH"` it fixes but when i restart the vscode, i get the same error.

I am using Kali Linux